# Bound the gradient of a smooth function $\nabla_y \Omega(y/|y|)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, chain-rule

I am reading a book about the Euler equation and in order to prove a stability result, study a property of a Calderon-Zygmund operator and at some point the author uses something I do not understand. We consider $\Omega : \mathbb S^{d-1} \to \mathbb R$ a smooth function such that it satisfies a cancelation property, i.e.
$$\int_{\mathbb S^{d-1}} \Omega (z) dz = 0.$$
At some point the author claim that we have
$$|\nabla_y \Omega (y/|y|)| \le C \frac{1}{|y|}$$
for $y \in \mathbb R^d$ and $y \neq 0$. I do not really get this result because if we look at it componentwise, we get
\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} \Omega \left(\frac{y}{|y|}\right)\bigg|&\le \sum_j\bigg|\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial z_j}\left(\frac{y}{|y|}\right)\bigg|\bigg|\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\left(\frac{y_j}{|y|}\right)\bigg|
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\left(\frac{y_j}{|y|}\right)\bigg| &= \bigg| \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|y|} - \frac{y_iy_j}{|y|^2}\bigg|\le  \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|y|} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{y_i^2 + y_j^2}{|y|^2} \le \frac{1}{|y|} + C
\end{align}
This eventually leads to
$$|\nabla_y \Omega (y/|y|)| \le C\sup_{z}|\nabla_z \Omega(z)|\left(1 + \frac{1}{|y|}\right).$$
How did he get this $1/|y|$ as a bound ? I don't get it.

Comment: There is a slight error in the computation of the derivative of $y/|y|$. The derivative $\partial_{y_i} |y|$ is $y_i/|y|$; so $$ \partial_{y_i}(y_j/|y|) = \frac{|y| \delta_{ij} - y_j y_i/|y|}{|y|^2} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|y|} - \frac{y_i y_j}{|y|^3},$$ so the derivative is like $1/|y|$.

Comment: Ohhh yes right, thanks a lot!!